# MSDeploy Command Console

Tags: deployment, web, msdeploy, webdeploy

How to open the "MSDeploy Command Console" that I see in the video "http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy" at around 3 minutes, 40 secs

I could access that by pointing a cmd prompt to "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3" and then launching msdeploy.exe.

My question is, is this the only way, or there is some command prompt similar to what we have for visual studio command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string deployPath = @"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";
string deployScript ="-verb:sync -source:package='C\package.zip' -dest:auto"
string scr = string.Format( "/k \"{0}\" {1}", deployPath, deployScript );
Process proc = new Process();        
proc = Process.Start( "cmd.exe", scr + " > error.txt" );
```

This way you call cmd and they inside you run the deployPath specified and by deployScript you say what you want msdeploy to do. /k keeps the console opened so you can see the result and finally > error.txt is there in order to save the output in a file (still working on sending the error)